# How to use class variables in callbacks in CoffeScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript, scope, angular-promise

```
class IndexCtrl
        constructor: (@Auth) ->
            @name = 'John'

        login: ->
            @Auth.login({email: @name, password: @password}).then(
                (user)->,
                (error)->
                    console.log @name
                )
```

In console i get ***(an empty string)***.
What should i do to use my @name in this callback?

Comment: Probably replace `(error)->` with `(error)=>`, i have never used coffee though... But give it a try...

Comment: I made this work like this:
login: ->;vm = this;@Auth.login({email: @name, password:@password}).then((user)->,(error)->console.log vm.name)

but i dont like this method.

Comment: Thats what `=>` is for.